# cannot open boost/regex.hpp

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I tried using Boost regex in my cpp project.
I have followed the steps listed in http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/how-to-use-the-boost-compiled-libraries-in-windows/

Then I just wrote

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
```

in my cpp file in my project. Then when I run 'make' in that directory I got the following error.

> cannot open include file: 'boost/regex.hpp': No such file or directory

Note: I was not using a new solution in visual studio. I tried this in an existing solution by adding the includes and libraries in project properties (followed the instructions in the above link)

Comment: have you tried `#include <boost/regex.hpp>`?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for what the difference is between `#include <filename>` and `#include "filename"`

Comment: @SteveLorimer I have tried both. Same issue persists. The boost files and my project files are in different drives. Is that a problem ? I have added the boost include directory in the VC++  Directory general configuration. So I guess different directories won't pose an issue ?